# retrieve pointers in a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct, variable-assignment, dereference

I ant to receive populate a structure with data (including pointers) in a function to which I pass a pointer of the structure that is to be populated. Now I realized that I lose the pointers upon exiting the function, hence I believe I might need to use a double pointer. Is that correct? I came up with a sample program which compiles but runs into a seg fault (line 43) due to access of invalid pointers in `main()`, please see below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM 100

typedef enum state_e {
        SM_ANALYZE = 0,           
        SM_TX,                    
        SM_PEND,                  
} state_t;

typedef struct data_s {
        int flags;             
        int id;                
        int local_min_tx;      
        int local_min_rx;      
        int local_detect_mult; 
        int egr_obj;           
        int label;             
        int egress_label;      
        int port;              
        state_t state;
}data_t; 

typedef struct content_s{
        state_t state;
        data_t *pData;
        void (*cbck)(data_t*,state_t);
}content_t;

static content_t MyCont[NUM]={0};
static data_t MyDat[NUM]={0};

void callback(data_t *pDat,state_t state);

int main(void)
{
content_t locC = {0};
callback_reg(1,callback);
data_set(1,&MyCont[1],SM_PEND);
data_get(1,&locC);


printf("cbck %p\ndata %p\nstate %d\nlabel %d",locC.cbck,
                                              locC.pData,
                                              locC.state,
                                              locC.pData->label);

MyCont[1].cbck(&MyDat[1],MyDat[1].state);
}

void callback(data_t *pDat,state_t state)
{
        printf("in user callback!\n");
        printf("BFDId %d is now %d\n",pDat->id,state);
        return;
}
int data_set(int id, content_t *pDat, state_t state)                
{                                                                           
        pDat->pData = &MyDat[id];
        pDat->state = state;
}                                                                           

int callback_reg(int id, void (*cb)(data_t*,state_t))        
{                                                                           
    MyCont[id].cbck=cb;
}                                                                           
int data_get(int id, content_t *pDat)
{
    pDat = &MyCont[id];
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you indicate the line that causing the problem? It's tedious to find the line 43 by counting it one by one.

Comment: Your `data_get` function says it will return an int, yet it does not, data_set and callback_reg are the same, undefined behavior #1. Why don't you just return the pointer?

Comment: @ZamronyP.Juhara sure, sorry! It's the `printf90` in `main()` that's causing the issue

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes, that's a copy and paste failure from my main application where I need to return an error code - or I guess I could return NULL on error and check for that at where the caller sits...

Comment: Please post your real compilable code if you want to get an answer that will be helpful. Right now your code could be crashing for several reasons, not just your pointer problem.

Comment: @RetiredNinja it runs fine for me to the final `printf()`. I compiled with `gcc -o test2 -g test2.c`

Comment: The code as posted potentially corrupts the stack 3 times before your printf, which pulls it's arguments from the stack. Do you see how the first case of undefined behavior makes your program invalid? Yes you have a problem assigning a pointer as well, but until you solve the other issues it isn't your only problem. Perhaps you should also compile with -Wall.

Comment: `pDat = &MyCont[id];` --> `*pDat = MyCont[id];`. Also Put prototype of function before use it. And The return type of a function that does not return a value should be `void`.

Comment: In `data_set()` you assign pointer with address of `MyDat[id]`. See `pDat.pData = &MyDat[id]`. But you initialized it with zero.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks a bunch! You can move your comment into an answer if you wish me to accept it, it's what helped me get it going and I'm now digging through all the other warnings!

Comment: Sidenote: if you are on a POSIX system, names with `_t` suffix are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: There is no stack in the C language. You certainly mean _undefined behaviour_.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
int data_get(int id, content_t *pDat)
{
  pDat = &MyCont[id];
}
```

the *local* variable `pDat` is assigned a value and then the function is left and `pDat` is deallocated as being local.

What you want is:

```
#include <errno.h> /* for errno */

/*
 * Gets content_t from MyConf at index id.
 *
 * Returns 0 on success or -1 on error.
 */
int data_get(size_t id, content_t *pDat)
{
  int result = 0;

  if (NULL == pDat)
  {
    errno = EINVAL;
    result = -1;
  }
  else if (NUM <= id) 
  {
    errno = ERANGE;
    result = -1;
  }
  else
  {
    *pDat = MyCont[id]; /* Copy MyCont[id] to where pDat points. */
  }

  return result;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for EXIT_FAILURE */
#include <stdio.h> /* for perror() */

int data_get(int, content_t *);

int main(void) 
{
  ..
  if (-1 == data_get(1,&locC))
  {
    perror("data_get(1, ...) failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILUE);:
  }
```

Comment: I have always thought (mental defect) that `if (data_get(1,&locC) = -1)` flowed better to my eyes -- while understanding it doesn't make a 'hill of beans' difference. 6 to 1, 1/2 dozen to another I guess....

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: [Why I prefer "*Yoda Conditions*".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions#Advantage)

Comment: It certainly shows that the *"Force Is With You"*... I think I just need more Jedi training...